# How to launch photo app from web page

Tags: ios, launch, photos

By searching the net and this forum I believe there is no way to use URL scheme to launch the native photo app?

In case I am wrong let me know (it might change someday iOS6?)

Anyone knows another photo app that I can launch and be able to specify the path to a folder or picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no url scheme available for launching the Native photo app of apple till now (10-November-2012).

You will get a list of third party photo app's that can be opened using the url schemes [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

Make sure you are installed the third party application before launching it with the url scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your help this is very useful. At this point I found 2 apps handling pictures that can be launched: good reader can be launched with a specific fle name, but photo viewing is not very smooth. Files pro is much better but so far I could only launch the app but did not find how to specify a folder or a file... still searching...